# Email Validation with DataBinding

Tags: android, validation, kotlin, mvvm, data-binding

I am trying to perform an email validation using data-binding

### viewModel

```
val email= MutableLiveData<String>()


fun signup(){


}
```

### XML

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/inputEmail"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:textInputCheck="@{viewModel.email}"
>

<EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="E-Mail"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:text="@={viewModel.email}" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>




<Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/signup"
        android:onClick="@{()->viewModel.signup()}"
/>
```

### Binding adapter

```
@BindingAdapter("textInputCheck")
fun textInputCheck(textInputLayout: TextInputLayout, email: String?) {
    Log.i("BindingAdapter", "${email}")
   if (email == null) {
        return
    }
    if (!email.validateEmail()) {
        textInputLayout.error = "Email format is not correct"
        return
    }
    textInputLayout.error = ""

}
```

`validateEmail()` is an custom extension function.

I managed with this code to show the error on the text input field but the view model doesn't know about that error and that's my problem!

### SUMMARY OF THE CODE & PROBLEM

I store the email in the ViewModel variable (`email`) then it checks the input using the data binding adapter then shows the error message on the textinput field,
I've also linked the button to the ViewModel signup function through XML.

So now I need a way to get that error back from the data binding adapter to the ViewModel and store it there in a variable, then when I click on the button I check that var and show an error message.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Have you visited this link https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/architecture#livedata ?

Comment: Have you got any solution to this? I'm also looking for the same solution